# What's wrong with this regular expression containing math symbols? (Ruby/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
text.scan(/\"[\d\w\s\+\-\*\/]*\"/)
```

I'm simply looking to find any thing within quotations that can contain letters, numbers, spaces, plus, minus, star, or forward slash. Everything works great in console. Each of the following works in a browser:

```
"abc"
"123"
"x-1" or "x - 1"
"x/1" or "x / 1"
```

But the plus sign and star fail in a browser (despite working fine in console with the same regex). Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit #1: I'm performing a quick gsub to add some formatting to the results of the scan. If the quotations have a plus or star in them, they don't even get picked up by the scan. The same code and text pasted in console works just fine.

Edit #2: I figured out a better way to frame this question without extraneous details and got the answer. "[Why can't I perform a gsub on each of the results from a scan if the result contains regex special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100765/why-cant-i-perform-a-gsub-on-each-of-the-results-from-a-scan-if-the-result-cont/)"

Comment: What do you mean, "fail in a browser"?

Comment: After scanning for the expressions I do a little gsub to add some formatting to them, but it doesn't pick up any expressions with the plus sign(+) or the star(*).

Comment: surely not your problem but just as an aside, you don't need to escape quotations, or most characters inside a character set.  `/"[-\d\w\s+*\/]*"/` should be essentially equivalent.  The only required escaped character would be the `/`.  The `-` would require escape if it was between 2 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that this problem was related to regexp string insertion (`/#{whatever}/`) not escaping special characters - manually escaping clears it up (`/#{Regexp.escape(whatever)}/`).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100765) for a full example/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean "work in browser" but I'm making an assumption that you're trying to parse an URL. In URL the `+` & `*` signs can be converted to `%2B` & `%2A` respectively.

Try this regexp:

```
/"[(\d\w\s\+\-\*\/|%2B|%2A)]+"/
```

...or decode URL before parsing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for URL's. I'm looking for math.

Comment: @Preacher Ok, then explain what do you mean by `browser', `console` etc. It's impossible to understand.