# Why can't I perform a gsub on each of the results from a scan if the result contains regex special characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a variation of "[What's wrong with this regular expression containing math symbols? (Ruby/Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909567/whats-wrong-with-this-regular-expression-containing-math-symbols-ruby-rails/)".

I can't understand why this `scan` followed by a `gsub` doesn't work on the plus sign (`+`). It also fails when the pattern contains other regex special characters like the asterisk (`*`), and the caret (`^`).

```
~ > irb
>> text = %(test &radic;x+1 &radic;x-1 &radic;x&times;1 &radic;/1)
=> "test &radic;x+1 &radic;x-1 &radic;x&times;1 &radic;/1"
>> radicals = text.scan(/&radic;[^\s]*/)
=> ["&radic;x+1", "&radic;x-1", "&radic;x&times;1", "&radic;/1"]
>> radicals.each do |radical|
?>   text = text.gsub(/#{radical}/, 'hello')
>> end
=> ["&radic;x+1", "&radic;x-1", "&radic;x&times;1", "&radic;/1"]
>> text
=> "test &radic;x+1 hello hello hello"
```

As you can see in the fifth line the `scan` finds the matching pattern with the plus sign (`+`), but when I try to perform the `gsub` on each of the results the pattern with the plus sign gets ignored. Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you substitute strings into regexps with the `/#{string}/` style, special characters (like `+`) don't get escaped.  I expect you want to use:

```
radicals.each do |radical|
    text = text.gsub(/#{Regexp.escape(radical)}/, 'hello')
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome. I had tried the escape, but in the wrong way. Thanks. BTW, if you post this as an answer to my other question I'll accept it there, too.